# How do I figure why my App is flagged as invalid Binary in apple store even if it was accepted for test flight?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I have been trying to deliver my first App to Apple store. I am using Github CI to maek the compiling.  It works and I can  submit and use it in test flight, yet, when I submit for publishing I get an Invalid binary immediately (I would think  such a test would have been done on the submission for test flight...)

```
ITMS-90111: Invalid Toolchain - Your app was built with a beta version of Xcode or SDK. Apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the GM version of Xcode 10.1 and the SDK for iOS 12.1 and watchOS 5.1, Xcode 7.1 and the SDK for tvOS 9, or Xcode 6 and the SDK for macOS 10.9 or later.
```

The message that I receive  just says that I might have used a beta version of  XCode, but that is not the case, I used 14.1 and I already tried using every single version available on the continuous integration, so I ruled out that.  I have seen  scattered on the web  people with  same message that found out  it was a random error of setup on the project, sometimes was an Apple bug in the review.

I  am new to Apple development so I  am wondering if there is a proper process for me to try to figure this out.   I can post the Plist.Info in case someone  can spot something wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<!--    <key>CFBundleIconName</key>
    <string>AppIcon</string>-->

    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>

    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>REDACTED</string>

    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
        
    <!-- Executable Name -->
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string> REDACTED</string>

    <!-- Info for finder -->
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>REDACTED</string>
       
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>

    <!-- Name displayed -->
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>REDACTED</string>

    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    
    <!-- Unique bundle name across AppStore -->
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>REDACTED</string>

    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>

    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>en_US</string>
        <string>pt_BR</string>
    </array>

    <!-- Short Version -->
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>0.1</string>

    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>0.1</string>

    <key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
    <string>iphoneos</string>
        
        <!---
            <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
    <string>16.2</string>

    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>14.0</string>

    <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
    <string>20C52</string>

    <key>DTXcode</key>
    <string>1420</string>
    -->
        
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>arm64</string>
    </array>
    
    <key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
    <array>
        <string>iPhoneOS</string>
    </array>

    <!-- Bundle Version to detect update on AppStore -->
    
    <!--

    <key>CSResourcesFileMapped</key>
    <true/>-->
 
        <!---<key>DTCompiler</key>
        <string> com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0</string>-->

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Aquila Medical Innovation Copyright 2023</string>

    <!-- Ui Orientation -->
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>

       
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>https</string>
    </array>



    <!--
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
            <string>Images</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
   -->
    
</dict>
</plist>
```

I tried pruning the  info.plist of all that seemed non necessary (to reduce conflict chances) and I tried  some 5 different toolchains and none were "beta" (So I ruled out the error message as being true).